# Application design using Fragments, ViewPager, PullToRefresh

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm now working on the Android application which main Activity extends [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (support library). This activity contains [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) view, which adapter is [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). To be exact, the adapter is a custom subclass, which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Adapter class has getItem() method to return a Fragment instance. I store these fragments within SparseArray not to create new fragment each time getItem() called. When the activity is destroyed, I clear this array, so I hope to create all of these fragments again when activity is recreated.

There is a scenario: user starts the app, then goes to the Android's Home (Launcher) screen, works with another apps, then Android OS kills our application to free up memory. When the user comes back to our application (it is not restarted from the very beginning, but is recreated and resumed from the place user has leaved it on), I watch the following sequence of callback calls:

```
Application: onCreate() called
Fragment: onAttach() called
Fragment: onCreate() called
Activity: onCreate() called
Fragment: onViewCreated() called
Activity: onStart() called
```

There are more than one Fragment (ViewPager calls getItem() for the current one and the two its neighbors - next and previous), but let's consider there's only one fragment to simplify it.

I used to think that activity's onCreate() should be called earlier than the fragments ones. This **only** happens when the app is brought back from background state being previously killed by the OS.

*I want to perform some background action before displaying anything within this activity (including fragments, so I don't want their onCreate() methods to be called so early). How may I do this in the described case?*

Comment: When to check and update data is really specific based on what your app actually does.  If your app has dynamic data that it pulls from a remote source then you might want to update your data at a 15-30 minute interval.  If your app is showing live results, you might want to poll more frequently.  If your app uses static data then you'll only ever have to load your data once and never check it again.  It's hard to know when you should check data without knowing what your app is doing.

Comment: Ok, let's consider this is not data loading but some generic action which is to be performed before displaying anything.

I probably asked the wrong question in the end, because it is very interesting to me why that happens?

Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's better to use [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) callback to ensure that the host activity is created at the moment. So there is no need to do something vital with UI within Fragment's [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method.